# Spring Boot wsdl first - change url to wsdl

Tags: java, web-services, spring-boot, wsdl

I'm using Spring Boot 1.3.* to build a contract first web service. I looked at the answer for the question at [How to use WSDL with spring-boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33773346/how-to-use-wsdl-with-spring-boot) . This worked fine

```
@EnableWs
@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
    servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
    return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/ws/*");
}

//http://localhost:8080/ws/services.wsdl --bean name is set to 'services'
@Bean(name = "services")
public Wsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition() {
    SimpleWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new SimpleWsdl11Definition();
    wsdl11Definition.setWsdl(new ClassPathResource("/schema/MyWsdl.wsdl")); //your wsdl location
    return wsdl11Definition;
}
}
```

My wsdl is now located at http://localhost:8080/ws/services.wsdl . Problem is that the application that will be the consumer of this web service requires the wsdl url to be written as

```
http://localhost:8080/ws/services?wsdl
```

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Would you use something like urlrewrite? Shall I provide that solution?

Comment: That just might do the trick, so yes.

Comment: Do you work with tomcat container? http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/ can you do these setup? Otherwise it will not work :(

Comment: I'm using tomcat. I do not have a web.xml, but I guess I can write UrlRewriteFilter as a @Bean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To configure urlrewrite as a bean check this [tuckey-url-rewrite-filter-java-class-configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32917184/tuckey-url-rewrite-filter-java-class-configuration)

This will forward in backend and user will not be notified. Ad this rule in your urlrewrite.xml

```
<rule>
    <from>/ws/services?wsdl</from>
    <to>/ws/services.wsdl</to>
</rule>
```

Comment: I will try this, thank you! Will let you know when/if i succeed.

Comment: I had to use web.xml to do it, but it works. So this is a valid solution, thank you.