# Apache CXF wsdl response issue

Tags: java, spring-boot, web-services, soap, cxf

I am trying to do a POC where I am not able to change where the soap client gets their WSDL definition. This soap client has a `".wsdl"` hardcoded in their code when they instantiate the service I am POCing. To start I have a pretty simple service, basically, a hello world which can be found here: https://github.com/apache/cxf/tree/master/distribution/src/main/release/samples/jaxws_spring_boot/src/main/java/sample/ws

The issue I am having is that I can't figure out how to configure jaxws or apache CXF to switch the WSDL URL response from http://localhost:8080/Service/Hello?wsdl to http://localhost:8080/Service/Hello.wsdl

I removed the metrics part from the example above and my WebServiceConfig looks like this:

```
@Bean
public Endpoint endpoint() {
    EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(bus, new HelloPortImpl());
    endpoint.publish("/Hello");
    return endpoint;
}
```

Is there any way to get apache CXF to respond with the WSDL document from  `localhost/<myservice>.wsdl` instead of `localhost/<myservice>?wsdl`

I feel like I am missing something really obvious.

Comment: Please find the answer here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35698046/spring-boot-wsdl-first-change-url-to-wsdl

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing is probably to issue a redirect or if the client doesn't honor that configure a rewrite rule.

You can also switch from a code first approach to a contract (WSDL) first approach and save the WSDL document somewhere else.

`?wsdl` is hard-coded in several places inside CXF and therefore not just a configuration to change.

Comment: Yea thanks, I ended up using https://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/ to rewrite the url to support what I needed thank you.